# convert_to_r_dataframe module object has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas, rpy2

I am new to python and learning pandas. I want to convert a pandas data frame "datframe" to an R-style data frame (to use rpy2 later). To this end I have the following two lines in my code:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com  
r_dataframe = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(datframe)
```

The first command goes through but then I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    r_dataframe = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(datframe)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'convert_to_r_dataframe' "
```

I am not sure why this is happening and how to troubleshoot it. Earlier in the code I have
import pandas as pd
Could this be the problem?

I am using python 2.7.3, rpy2-2.3.2 and 2.15.3

Comment: From rpy2-2.3.3, you can optionally use an automagic converter that would make the calls to `convert_to_r_dataframe` unnecessary in many (or even most) cases. `from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri; pandas2ri.activate()` should be all you need (pandas data frames will be converted implicitly whenever R functions are called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me:

```
>>> import rpy2
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import pandas.rpy.common as com
>>> rpy2.__version__
'2.3.1'
>>> pd.__version__
'0.10.0'
>>> datframe = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 3], 'b' : [3, 4, 5]})
>>> r_df = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(datframe)
>>> r_df
<DataFrame - Python:0x105b12710 / R:0x7fa8131d7918>
[IntVector, IntVector]
  a: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.IntVector'>
  <IntVector - Python:0x105b12ab8 / R:0x7fa8131d7838>
[       1,        2,        3]
  b: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.IntVector'>
  <IntVector - Python:0x105b12950 / R:0x7fa8131d7800>
[       3,        4,        5]
```

Different rpy2 version though..

Comment: >>> import rpy2
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import pandas.rpy.common as com
>>> 
>>> rpy2.__version__
'2.3.2'
>>> pd.__version__
'0.7.0'

Comment: could my earlier pd version be the problem? How do I upgrade to the latest?

Comment: worth trying, you could use pip: `sudo pip install --upgrade pandas` (edit: in fact the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html) says that conversion to R data.frame is added to pandas v0.8.0)

Comment: That seems to be it. I upgraded to pd._version_ '0.10.1' and no more error. Thank you very much.