# How can I import R dataframes into Pandas?

Tags: python, r, import, pandas, dataframe

I am using R off and on as a "backend" to Python and thus need to occassionaly import dataframes from R into Python; but I can't figure out how to import an R `data.frame` as a Pandas `DataFrame`.

For example if I create a dataframe in R

```
rdf = data.frame(a=c(2, 3, 5), b=c("aa", "bb", "cc"), c=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

and then pull it into Python using `rmagic` with

```
%Rpull -d rdf
```

I get

```
array([(2.0, 1, 1), (3.0, 2, 0), (5.0, 3, 1)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4')])
```

I don't know what this is, and it's certainly not the

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 3, 5], 'b': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'], 'c': [True, False, True]})
```

that I would expect.

The only thing that comes close to working for me is to use use a file to transfer the dataframe by writing in R

```
write.csv(data.frame(a=c(2, 3, 5), b=c("aa", "bb", "cc"), c=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)), file="TEST.csv")
```

and then reading in Python

```
pd.read_csv("TEST.csv")
```

though even this approach produces an additional column: "Unnamed: 0".

What is the idiom for importing an R dataframe into Python as a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pandas - how to convert r dataframe back to pandas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630121/pandas-how-to-convert-r-dataframe-back-to-pandas)

Comment: See also this comment from @lgautier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209636/convert-to-r-dataframe-module-object-has-no-attribute#comment21457740_15209636

Comment: @joris: Not a duplicate. Look closely at the question. This about dataframes created **in R**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: `array([(2.0, 1, 1), (3.0, 2, 0), (5.0, 3, 1)], dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4')])`. That is a `numpy` structured `array`. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html/. You can easily convert it to `pandas` DF by using `pd.DataFrame`:

```
In [65]:

from numpy import *
print pd.DataFrame(array([(2.0, 1, 1), (3.0, 2, 0), (5.0, 3, 1)], dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', '<i4')]))
   a  b  c
0  2  1  1
1  3  2  0
2  5  3  1
```

`b` column is coded (as if `factor()`'ed in `R`), `c` column was converted from `boolean` to `int`. `a` was converted from `int` to `float` (`'<f8'`, actually I found that unexpected)

2nd, I think `pandas.rpy.common` is the most convenient way of fetching data from `R`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html (It is probably too brief, so I will add another example here):

```
In [71]:

import pandas.rpy.common as com
DF=pd.DataFrame({'val':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3]})
r_DF = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(DF)
print pd.DataFrame(com.convert_robj(r_DF))
   val
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
```

Finally, the `Unnamed: 0` column is the index column. You can avoid it by providing `index_col=0` to `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: The second approach does nothing different from the first  — i.e., wrapping in `pd.DataFrame(com.convert_robj(rdf))` is no different from `pd.DataFrame(rdf)`. The first approach changes all the values in bizarre ways. It looks like the file export/import approach is the only way that works?

Comment: And: Thanks for the `index_col=0` tip. That definitely makes it import/export the preferred approach, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You are right, the only way I found that `string` data type is preserved is `%R z = c('a',1,'c')` and then `%Rpull z`. Putting it to a `data.frame` will always resulting it being converted to `int32/64`. A side note, on my machine the 2nd approach is slightly different from the 1st in that the resulting `DataFrame` has `int64` for all its columns, rather than a mixed bag of `dtypes`.

Comment: For the last one, on the `R` side, you can also do `write.csv(......, row.names=FALSE)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

What about this ([see pandas 0.13.1 documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html#transferring-r-data-sets-into-python)):

```
%load_ext rmagic
%R rdf = data.frame(a=c(2, 3, 5), b=c("aa", "bb", "cc"), c=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))

import pandas.rpy.common as com

print com.load_data('rdf')
   a   b      c
1  2  aa   True
2  3  bb  False
3  5  cc   True
```

Comment: rdf is your r data frame, rdf = data.frame(a=c(2, 3, 5), b=c("aa", "bb", "cc"), c=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))